# Отображение RTSP видео-потока в WinForms приложении на C#

Tags: c#, winforms, rtsp

Для отображения RTSP видео-потока (MPEG4) в существующем WinForms приложении используется библиотека `libvlc`, входящая в состав популярного плеера [`VLC`](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/). Однако, в коде самой библиотеки имеются дефекты, затрудняющие использование такого подхода в режиме 24/7. К этим дефектам в частности относятся: утечки ресурсов, случайное создание паразитных окон и взаимоблокировки.

В качестве альтернативы рассматривалась библиотека [`gstreamer`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/), но как я понял, её проблематично использовать в составе WinForms приложения.

Еще есть вариант использования DirectDraw, но пока неясно как там будут обстоять дела с получением потока по RTSP.

Требуется совет: как (с помощью каких технологий) оптимальнее, с точки зрения стабильности работы в первую очередь, реализовать функционал по отображению RTSP видео-потока в WinForms приложении? Сложность реализации вторична, но, конечно, не хотелось бы изобретать самокат, а использовать готовые высокоуровневые библиотеки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здравствуйте, сам недавно сталкивался с подобной задачей и пришел к варианту с использованием фреймворка **GStreamer**.

Реализовать взаимодействие C# WinForms и фреймворка GStreamer можно с помощью **P/Invoke**. Насколько я понимаю, можно так же использовать **C++/CLI**, но я данный метод не использовал, да и P/Invoke реализуется быстрее и подходит больше для прототипирования, а на C++/CLI соскочить можно будет потом, если понадобится "украсить" архитектуру и/или сделать дополнительный слой абстракции.

Если подробнее, то реализуется так: весь GStreamer бэкенд находится в C++ библиотеке, в свою очередь, фронтенд - C# WinForms приложение вызывающее GStreamer функционал из C++ библиотеки. Главная проблема, которая может возникнуть - отображение видеопотока в нужном окне/виджете/контролле. Черновое решение:

C#:

```
[DllImport("gstTest.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public extern static void play_file(StringBuilder path, IntPtr hwnd);
//...
void playFile(){
    IntPtr hwnd = outputWidget.Handle;
    play_file(new StringBuilder().Append("file:///A:/test.mp4"), hwnd);
}
```

C++:

```
void play_file(char* path, void* hwnd_ptr){
        gst_init(NULL, NULL);
        HWND hwnd = (HWND)hwnd_ptr;
        GstElement *pipeline = gst_element_factory_make("playbin", "player");
        g_object_set (G_OBJECT (pipeline), "uri", path, NULL);
        gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(pipeline), (guintptr)hwnd);
        //...
}
```

Comment: @alexolut всё использование GObject типов остается за дверями нашей библиотеки. Что именно Вы подразумеваете под `как наложить концепцию GObject`? 
Преобразование GObject типов в CLR типы? Тогда маршалинг. Вся реализация самой GStreamer библиотеки, кроме нюанса с хэндлером окна, сводится к разработке обычного GStreamer приложения/библиотеки.
Или Вы про какие-то конкретные вещи?

Comment: Когда я смотрел на вариант с `gstreamer`, я не видел `gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle`. Наверное потому что смотрел версию `0.1`, а не `1.0`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким документом Вы руководствовались при сборке под windows, а так же версию `gstreamer` и компилятор.

Comment: @alexolut скорее всего, аналогичная функция и в 0.10 есть: `gst_x_overlay_set_window_handle ()`. Но версия 0.10 устарела и Вам следует использовать 1.0(думаю, Вы это и так знаете, но лучше сказать). Вся документация есть на [официальном сайте](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/), в частности [это](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/manual.pdf), а так же [перевод нескольких частей на русском](http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/BOOKS/gstreamer/00-pred.html)...

Comment: @alexolut ...Что-то конкретно под Windows нашел только [это](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-integration-win32.html)(тут и про компилятор есть), так же можно использовать туториалы для 0.10 на [сайте 0.10](http://docs.gstreamer.com), их для старта работы побольше будет.

Comment: Мне удалось собрать/запустить тестовые примеры `c++` под `vs2013`. Но пока всё ещё не ясно как интегрировать цикл обработки сообщений `gstreamer` на основной (gui) поток WinForms.

Comment: @alexolut Вы хотите запускать цикл обработки сообщений в потоке C# GUI? Если да, то это зафризит Ваш пользовательский интерфейс. GMainLoop стоит вызывать из другого потока.

Comment: несмотря на то, что он рисует на хендле формы? Я считал, что использовать элементы GUI можно только из GUI потока.

Comment: @alexolut Вам и не надо вызывать само воспроизведение видео из другого потока, только обработка сообщений должна вызываться из другого потока. Вы можете вообще убрать обработку сообщений и не запускать GMainLoop(ради наглядности и задач прототипирования). Все остальное будет в родном потоке.

Comment: Вчерне заработало. Теперь надо убедиться, что работает стабильнее, чем `vlc`. Спасибо.

Comment: @alexolut рад, что вышло. Отпишите, как получите результаты - интересно же :)

Comment: немного [о результатах](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277891/deadlock-in-gstreamer-for-windows).

Answer (score 1):

Если RTSP поток передаётся в формате mjpeg, то можно попробовать класс Capture из Emgu CV.

Если RTSP поток передаётся в формате H.264, то изображение почти совсем не отображается без лагов

Comment: Поток в MPEG4 (добавил в вопрос). А какого рода лаги проявляются?

Comment: @alexolut с mpeg4 не сталкивался. Лаги - вместо нижней части изображения отображается или шум, или копия самого нижнего из прогрузившихся слоёв пикселей